# How to check AppCompatActivity comes from which fragment in Android

Tags: java, android

I can pass an AppCompatActivity through a function parameter from a Fragment. But I can't figure out how to check which fragment pass inside that function. How **instanceof** checking could be possible.

Suppose, I have two fragments.

1. OptionsFragment
2. HomeFragment

Both Can pass **AppCompatActivity** like this.

```
StaticAccess.checkSignal((AppCompatActivity) OptionsFragment.this.getActivity())
```

**Or**

```
StaticAccess.checkSignal((AppCompatActivity) HomeFragment.this.getActivity())
```

Inside StaticAccess Class...

```
public class StaticAccess{

    public static void checkSignal(final AppCompatActivity context){
        //how to check context is instanceof which fragment when 
        //if(context instanceof OptionFragment) not comparable
    }

}
```

Comment: why do you want to pass the activity? Simple way for same result: Create a `BaseFragmentClass` for OptionsFragment and HomeFragment and just pass them to `checkSignal(BaseFragmentClass currentFragment)` and check if `currentFragment is OptionsFragment` or HomeFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare `Activity` with a `Fragment` (for obvious reasons), they are totally separate things. A `Fragment` is not bound to any particular `Activity`, it can be triggered from any `Activity`.
When you pass `OptionsFragment.this.getActivity()`, you are not passing the `Fragment`, you are passing the `Activity` that the `Fragment` is currently in. So the `context` in your `checkSignal()` function is of the `Activity`.
There are a couple of ways to go about it, and it all depends on what implementation you use in your app.
For example, if you have a patter where `OptionsFragment` and `HomeFragment` are always called from separate activities, Then for example if `OptionsFragment` was triggered from `Activity1` and `HomeFragment` from `Activity2` in your `checkSignal` function you would do something like `if (context instanceof Activity1) { // Do stuff }` etc. However, this would be a bad and not scalable approach in my opinion.
Now, if your patter is such that the `checkSignal` function is only called from `Fragments`, then you can change the constructor to `static void checkSignal(final Fragment context)`, call the function from the fragment like `StaticAccess.checkSignal(this)`, and check for the type like this `if (context instanceof HomeFragment) { // Do stuff }`. However, this too is a bad and not scalable approach.
If I were you, I would create an `enum` with the different possible signal types, and pass that as the parameter. This will remove the dependency of whether you call it from an `Activity`, `Fragment`, or wherever you want (especially since it is `static`, it can be called from anywhere). Something like this:

```
public enum SignalSource {
    HOME,
    OPTIONS
}

public class StaticAccess{

    public static void checkSignal(SignalSource source){
        if (source == SignalSource.HOME) {
            // Do something...
        } else if (source == SignalSource.OPTIONS) {
            // Do something...
        }
    }

}

// Call it like this from anywhere
StaticAccess.checkSignal(SignalSource.HOME)
```

Comment: Thanks now i can understand whole process